# Repeat directive N times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside directive's link function first I want to fetch some value suppose I get N, then I want to pass this value in scope to repeat N times directive.

Problem is every time directive instantiate link function repeat the execution of code that fetch value N.

for fetching value I want this code to be execute exactly once not every time. I tried with compile function but the problem is I would not be able access scope inside compile function.

Also based on requirement I don't want to write this code in parent scope controller.

any help would be great help

Thanks in advance

Comment: So cache request and don't make it more than once. However, ideally if you move this loading data code to controller and pass it to directive.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But as I wrote above in my question that I couldn't write in parent controller. I have to write it in directive only. Because of some logic I wouldn't be knowing what data we have in controller this value only I get when directive called. That is why I want to write in directive and second thing I want to make my controller thinner also.

Comment: Let me explain situation a bit more. 

I am using WEB-SQL in my project in which I have a table called 'PAGE'
now what happen as my application start my controller fetch api and my view render a directive called 'FIRST-DIRECTIVE'. 

Now 'FIRST-DIRECTIVE' template itself contain one more directive call 'SECOND-DIRECTIVE' now second directive need to be repeat for each record in 'PAGE' table. so I want to fetch data from 'PAGE' once and I want to repeat 'SECOND-DIRECTIVE' for each page.

This is the complete requirement.

Comment: I would create pageService and use it in directive. Directive is not very good place for requests anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the problem is suppose I will do
 
    var pages = pageService.fetchAllPage() inside link function

and scope.noOfPages = pages
but the problem will remain same every time service will be called it will set value in scope.

Comment: @KhalidHussain I have not written code till now because I am not getting the best way of doing this.